# POSIX shared memory - How many copies of memory are there

Tags: c, linux, posix, ipc, shared-memory

**Situation:**

If process a & b each use `mmap()` to create a shared memory mapping, with the same shared memory object `/shm-a` as backed file.

**My guess:**

I originally thought there is only 1 copy of memory, which processes write/read on.

But later I think there are actually 3 copy of them, right? Each process has 1 copy which is created by `mmap()`, and the 3rd copy is the shared memory object, which is used to sync between process, but I am not sure.

**The questions are:**

- Then how many copy of memory there are? **1** or **n+1** (where ***n*** is process count)
- If it's **n+1**, won't this be a kind waste of memory? And is it proper for process to read/write to the shared memory object via its `fd` directly?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why that is would be called **shared** memory if there were multiple memory areas ...

Comment: When I share a book my natural instincts is to use the photocopier!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then how many copy of memory there are? 1 or n+1 (where n is process count)

There is only one copy of the shared memory.

The same physical memory is mapped into different processes. But it may be mapped to *different* addresses.

> And is it proper for process to read/write to the shared memory object via its fd directly?

Yes it is. That is, in fact, the purpose of shared memory. What one process writes into shared memory can be read by the other process. This a very fast form of IPC. But you do have to be careful in how you use it. In particular, you need to worry about concurrent access, and sharing pointers in shared memory.

Comment: So, when create `mmap()` with a disk file as backed file, the process need to allocate memory by itself for the disk file; but when use shared memory object as backed file, the project simply map it into process's virtual address, without create another copy of memory in the middle, is that so?

Comment: What you are calling allocating memory in a disk backed `mmap()` - is really just sizing the file on the disk to match the size of the mapped memory. Think of it as a system that involves three elements - a virtual address space in each process, physical memory that the virtual memory is mapped to, and the backing store object (which can be a disk file, or a shared memory segment). For shared memory, there is only one copy of actual physical memory for all involved processes.

Comment: I know for shared memory there is only one copy, what I am not sure is does each process allocate another memory up the shared memory, just like what it do in case where the backed file is a regular disk file and anonymous mapping when there is no backed file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The process does *not* allocate any memory for disk file backed `mmap()`.

Comment: I doubt that, for anonymous mapping it surely allocate memory, otherwise, where it write data to? And for disk file, I think there is a similar case, as `man mmap()` says `The contents of a file mapping are initialized using length bytes starting  at offset offset in the file (or other object) referred to by the file descriptor fd`. Even though it might delay allocation, but I think there should have extra memory allocation in this 2 case.

Comment: Well, as I said, when you use `mmap()`, virtual memory is mapped into the process address space, This virtual memory is mapped to physical memory as and when necessary. The memory is `swapped` to the backing object when necessary (be it disk file, or shared memory segment). Other than this, the process itself does not allocate any memory. And the answer to your question is that for shared memory, there is only 1 copy of physical memory in all `n` processes. I am not sure which part you are stumbling on. Maybe you can explain.

Comment: You can read the above comment, I think it's quite clear about why I have doubt. And I think your point about file mapping with shared memory object as backed file is clear, I think the doubt is about `mmap()`'s behavior with different type of backed file, or no backed file. Ok, I will check the kernel source code for that, and update this post if I got any spark.